# agm-map is not a known element angular 4

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use [Angular Google Maps (AGM)](https://angular-maps.com/) in my Angular project, but this error was appeared *agm-map is not a known element*.

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDpV2SN0k5BqyVTQjTX8wU - hdCgBgktKY0'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  lat = 51.678418;
  lng = 7.809007;
}
```

My app.component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

[image]

Comment: Just restart your editor

Comment: I did it but same problem occurred

Comment: Reinstall the agm map again

Comment: I've you already installed it, try to kill `npm` and run `npm start` again

Comment: I have also this problem also, with Angular 6.1

Answer (score 3):

Try to import the AgmModule in your own modules.

```
 import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

 @NgModule({
 imports:[
      AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
       apiKey: 'YOUR API KEY'
     }) 
    ]
 })

 export class MyModule { }
```

more details in: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1563

Answer (score -3):

It giving that error because it can't find the agm/core where agm map is stored , and i see you already have an import statement for it, so you should just re-install agm/core using

> npm install @agm/core --save

For a better explanation visit https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/